# Under what conditions would a cybercommunist nation form?

Tags: planets, politics, far-future

In an imagined future timeline, over 350 years from now, humans have terraformed Mars and colonised Venus, along with constructing a score of rotating space habitats. These worlds are mostly governed by federal or direct republics, but the difficulty faced with governing an entire planet means that, eventually, a new form of governance is needed.

Thus is laid the foundations for the rise of **Cybercommunism,** a subset of communism where advanced computer systems see that everyone remains equal, managing the economy with the precision of a calculator. This puts less of a strain on governments, who thus need only to represent the people and so wield much less power.

however, I am struggling to find a pretext for cybercommunism to replace conventional democracy on such a large scale and on several planets. Any ideas?

Comment: Uggghhh... The end goal of the Communist movement is not and has never been to *"see that everyone remains equal"*. Making sure that everybody remains equal is trivially easy, and is in the end a Bad Thing, because it can only mean that everybody is equally poor and equally illiterate. The goal of Communism is to make sure that everybody is (1) free and (2) has the means to become the best he can become. And "managing the economy with the precision of a calculator" is meaningless; managing the economy is *always* subordinated to some set of overall goals, and the goals are set by people.

Comment: What is "equal"? Does the dish washer, waste management engineer, life support scientist, and brain surgeon get the same housing, food, and entertainment allotment?

Comment: Your describing a bureaucracy. A functional and fair bureaucracy executes all requests with the same rubric. Whether a computer makes the decisions is not really relevant. Whether your people have elected officials or not is also not relevant to the bureaucracy's existence and function, except when those elected officials propose to change bureaucratic rules. Every successful government has a bureaucracy.

Comment: Regarding "managing the economy with the precision of a calculator": you may want to take a look at the [socialist calculation debate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_calculation_debate).

Comment: Cybercommunism isn't new.  It is, in fact, the origin of the word "Cyber".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Cybersyn   So, to what extent does your colony look like Chile?

Comment: Note that you are presenting communism and clashing with democracy, but there's no reason you couldn't have elections to determine who makes whatever decisions are required to run your AI or whatever. You just want the citizens to have an equal share in the resources that are produced (rather than have individuals own the means of production, as in capitalism)

Comment: Surely this question is brainstorming.

Comment: @SeanOConnor Surely. But fun.

Comment: @AlexP Uggghhhh </hyperbole>. Communism is an extreme socialism that attempts to resolve historically exploitive business relationships with common ownership. Both production and products are common property. Everyone owns everything, which is often shorthanded to "everyone is equal". In light of actual communism's attempted implementations in the world, that's not at all an inaccurate description. They attempted, or at least claimed they would, take the surpluses and distribute them to the deficits. "free" and "means to become the best he can be" is something you just made up.

Comment: @fredsbend: Once upon a time, because of how times where, I actually did study Marxism-Leninism and Scientific Socialism and Dialectical and Historical Materialism and the lot. Not my choice, it was a compulsory subject. For more than one year.  And I can with perfect clarity distinguish the philosphical theory from the historically determined praxis.

Answer (score 6):

**Rotating Space Habitats**

You already have the pretext.

1. The critical systems of the artificial habitat are already run by  AI. Of course the AI also runs the economy. It is the AI that makes sure we have enough oxygen and gravity. It is the AI that stops us being sucked out into empty space. It is the AI that makes course adjustments to keep us away from particle showers 12 years down the line. It is the AI that scans our body and calculates the correct mineral supplements. It is the AI that tinkers with our embryo's genetics to make them better suited to life in space. If you don't like it, you cannot come to the cylinder in the first place.
2. Fresh start. Even if everyone in Spain decided they wanted the country to become a Communism tomorrow -- and not a foney-baloney Soviet Union state capitalism either -- it would still take a long time and cause great disruption to turn a capitalistic country into a communist one. Your colony does not have that problem. They are building it from scratch. The first colonists are astronauts and engineers. Highly educated people tend to be more in favour of communism than the common man.

Comment: Unfortunately, the planetary colonies were established long before cybercommunism is meant to arise. However, I do like the notion that this form of government arises within space habitats, as it could then potentially spread across the solar system as democracy did in the 20th century.

Comment: @user98816 You are free to use a soft version of the same idea.

Comment: It was actually not the AI that decided you should get that tattoo you had to get.  Even though you thought it was.

Comment: @Willk Dang. And I thought the AI really wanted me to get a Fat Bottom Girls tattoo.

Answer (score 4):

## Democracies opposed AIs

Democracies had several disasters with AI involving mass casulties which led to them being extremely opposed to AIs. They saw them as world ending threats. This meant they couldn't benefit as much from very powerful computers.

## Cybercommunism embraced AI

Cybercommunism embraced AI. They were able to set up many communities in hard to live places like asteroids with the help of more mature AI technology. Their substantial successes thanks to AIs led to them spreading and displacing democracies over time.

Answer (score 2):

**Ineptitude**

Democracy has a fundamental flaw. People are called to decide on issues, either directly or indirectly (through elected officials).
The issue is that in either case the voter most likely is unable to grasp the implications of the decision and predict the likelyhood of outcomes.
This is more and more true as society becomes more complex.
So technicians are brought in to counsel but they often have a partial view of the problem, each one for their pertaining area. And this without considering corruption and conflicts of interest.
How to choose what is best?

For Democracy to work you need a large base of population with both a lot of time available to educate themselves and a good system of education. Children must be raised so they develop analytical and critical thinking, adults must be helped to hone their skills and have access to unbiased complete information.
I think we can all agree there is no nation on Earth where this is happening.
For the simple reason that an informed, critical population would be hard to be steered under the false mantle of Democracy the elites have woven.

As society becomes more complex problems may involve so many implications that our mind simply may not be able to deal with it. That is why managament is going to be passed to AI.
Trained AI will be able to play scenarios in safe sandboxes before applying changes in the real society. Costs and benefits and compensations will all have to be balanced in order to perform necessary functions while not disrupting the lives of the population.

Example:
A water waste recycling plant has to be installed so it can serve the needs of a city.
Where should it be placed?  What effect will it have on people's health? What about local agricultural production? What about housing depreciation? What kind of compensations could be put in place? How to find the budget for the project? And on and on and on.
All done in minutes by an AI.
Whereas traditional decision methods would involve political bargaining both at local and national level, involvement of private lobbyists, possible bribery, involvement of magistrates and so on. After years the project would still be to be done. After more years the project may have been done and the enormous costs to make it happen (with its bargaining, lobbying, bribing, judging costs) would all be passed down to the public to pay.

No more. People won't choose anymore, AI will. In a truly Cybercommunist way.
The change will not be sudden but inevitable. As the political representatives will fail again and again to address the complex challenges that society is facing. As the inadequacy of a system that will not consider factual, scientific explanations and predictions to take action become evident. As blubbering, feeble, elected officials put in position by the elites will have to face the enraged, impoverished and disillusioned crowds.

The question is: who controls AI?
And that is stuff for a good story or two.

Comment: Models require parameters - information about (for instance) the price of land, how waste water plants affect nearby house prices on average, etc..  What if somebody with a vested interest *lies* to the AI, feeding it false information, then turns round and says "Look, our infallible and impartial computer has spoken"?  Plot twists, that's what.  Or what if they didn't (maybe the AI is clever enough to see through that, even), but somebody else falsely claims they did?  More plot twists.

Comment: @A.B. See? It gets more and more interesting as you explore the possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

**Capitalism may not work for small, isolated colonies.**

Capitalism assumes that there is a market, and that some people own means of production, while all own their own labor, to sell at the market. The invisible hand of people acting in their self-interest and negotiating prices regulate production and consumption.

A space colony has few people, and everybody has a vital job to do, or that person would not be there. So you cannot justify why one earns more than another. You could still have a market to buy *some* things at the colony store, with *genuine Earth coffee* getting more expensive as it runs out, and cheaper when supply ships arrive. So one colonist could think he wants a coffee, and bid on that, while another colonist thinks she wants tea, and bid on that. And if few people want herbal tea, that becomes cheaper. But then, your colonists could decide that this is too disruptive. When the supply ship arrives, everybody gets *genuine Earth tea*, in between everybody drinks herbal so-called tea.

Some colonies might then transition to capitalism as they get larger and become **able to support** capitalism. Perhaps the values of their parent culture prompt them to do it as soon as possible. Other colonies never feel the pressing need.

You will also find people assuming that space colonies *can* go libertarian-capitalist much better than any place on Earth, because there are enough unclaimed plots so that everybody can 'go west' and stake a claim. Perhaps there are different societies in competition? Note also that assumptions on travel times and costs matter ...

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with what the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=definition+of+communism) teaches us:

> com·mu·nism /ˈkämyəˌnizəm/ a political theory derived from Karl Marx, advocating class war and leading to a society in which all property is publicly owned and each person works and is paid according to their abilities and needs.

**Class war**

It's easy to suggest that cybercommunism simply ignores that first part about advocating class war. That's too simplistic. A quick jaunt into [Wikipedia land](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_struggle) teaches us the following:

> Class struggle happens when the bourgeoisie (the rich) pay the proletariat (the workers) to make things for them to sell. The workers have no say in their pay or what things they make, since they cannot live without a job or money.

And here's part of the problem. People can live peacefully and happily *in any political system* if they want to. The development of Communism was due in no small part to real and perceived inequities between *those that have* and *those that have not.*

The problem that Communism always runs into and that your computer will run into is that those who have great talent and who are able to produce voluminously for the state are generally unhappy being economically equal to those who have little talent or who are unable (for any reason) to produce significantly for the state.

Oversimplifying outrageously, this is the problem with all state-sponsored welfare systems. Those who produce are (a) jealous that those who don't produce receive a free ride and (b) angry that any part of their production is used to provide for those who don't produce.

This is obviously an unfair simplification because there are those who, for reasons beyond their control, cannot produce and there are those who abuse the system because they could produce if they wanted to — and the nearly infinite spectrum of people in between.

But we'll stick with the simplification because you're going to have a problem with the proverbial over-achievers believing they deserve more than those they perceive are the proverbial under-achievers. And your computer *won't care.* In fact, it can't.

That's the bare essence of Communism.

So my first point is a [Frame Challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7097/40609): you have a class war, but it's a war that's *created by your computer* because it's enforcing the strict dictate of Communism that all property is publicly owned and people are paid only according to their abilities and needs.<sup>1</sup> And that creates unhappiness.

**The saving moderator: needs *and* abilities**

What has a hope of saving your desire for a cybercommunist "government" is that your computer isn't (or at least shouldn't) just pay everyone with *equity.*

And here we need to pause for a moment to remind the reader that there is a difference (a BIG difference) between "equality" and "equity." Equity suggests that two people deserve all things without variation in quality or quantity regardless of any differences that may exist between those two people. Equality suggests that those two people will receive those things with equity that both have an equal right to, but that they will receive other things due to perseverance, talent, and education (or, when terribly applied, due to privilege, circumstance, etc. I'm really not trying to grind an axe, the point is relevant).<sup>6</sup>

Communism *allows people who are greater contributors to society the privilege of having more based on their contributions* but refuses to apply that concept to everything. In its "ideal" form (if there is such a thing as an "ideal form"), Communism would be the preferred solution of a post-scarcity society where the *basic needs* of all people are met with equity but the *limited resources and opportunities* that always exist in society are given to those who show *merit* due to their value to the state.

History demonstrates that humans are *really bad* at making those kinds of judgements. Your computer, on the other hand, changes the game just a bit.

There are always limited resources. You can't, for example, build enough ski resorts to allow every person an equal chance to ski.<sup>2</sup> In your world (in any fictional universe), it's unbelievable that anyone can travel anywhere at anytime. No economy can support that (go read footnote #2).

So your computer is ensuring that everyone has a *basic amount of living space* and a *basic allotment of food* and *basic access to recreation,* etc. But it's also rewarding people for their abilities (the results of talent, education, and perseverance). If there is extra living space available, it's used to reward ability. Extra food? Extra recreation? Rewards. You can't tilt the scales too much or you have an unhappy majority that, on average, can't produce like the able minority.

But if you don't do that, you have unhappy over-achievers.

Either way, it leads to inconvenient things like sabotage, rebellion... you know... things that require unusual amounts of dry cleaning. I don't know which would be worse, a large group of rebels who don't have the skills of the able minority or the doomsday bombs of the able minority.

**Which leads us to Ayn Rand**

I figured we'd end up here (go read Footnote #1). When you say "cybercommunism" you're saying it with an idea in your head of what "Communism" means. I suspect that it's not equal to what Communism is.

True communism doesn't ignore merit. Ideal communism doesn't permit excess. Communism does not replace a money-based economy.<sup>3</sup> Communism assures all have their needs and that wants are "fairly distributed" based on value to the state, thereby (theoretically) avoiding class war by creating an *equitable balance between those who do more and those who do less.*

**So when you say "Communism," I'm taking you at your word**

**(BTW, TL;DR)**

What is the pretext? You're 90% of the way there if you have a [post-scarcity economy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-scarcity_economy) and an unemotional, unbiased, somewhat ruthless means of ensuring that the basics all people need are met with *equity.* No matter what the humans are doing to govern themselves, the society is already Communistic by nature.

*But if you're asking for the computer to fully embrace the job of government,* then we have something else to worry about. Computers are notoriously short of compassion.<sup>4</sup> When someone needs something beyond what equity allows due to something beyond their control, the computer must be capable of comprehending the reality of that loss of control, or it is unable to respond with excess beyond what it computes is the "fair share" due the person. That means the last 10% of pretext is this:

**You need a reason for people to hand control of their lives over to a computer**

Because without the ability to enforce the governing ideology, there is no guarantee it will remain stable. In fact, I'd hazard to guess it can't remain stable. There's always *someone* who's unhappy and willing to do something about it.

Handing lives over to a computer, of course, is the basis of uncounted SciFi stories over the last 125 years. Some people believe they would have no problem giving their life choices over to a computer (remember, "all property is publicly owned," that means your services, too), but I suspect that belief is due to the luxury of never having had anything forcefully denied them without recourse. And that's what your computer would do (see footnote #4).

So, IMO, your last pretext is time to let the [frog boil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling_frog). Your people need time to let the convenience of letting the computer deal with the awful, tedious day-to-day nonsense of living.<sup>5</sup> Eventually your people will realize that there's no need to have a Mayor because the computer is already doing all the work of managing the city. They don't need legislative representatives because the computer provides easy access to moderated debate and communal input to managing laws, ordinances, and regulations.

They don't need government because the computer is already doing all the work.

*Cybercommunism.*

Which is all fine and dandy until the computer instructs Mr. and Mrs. Jones that their 15 year-old child will be trained as a sewage treatment maintenance worker, which doesn't make any of them happy at all.

*Be careful what you wish for.*

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *If you want some fun, read* Atlas Shrugged *by Ayn Rand. Most people believe Capitalism is the opposite of Communism. That's not really true. Randian economics, also known as a "meritocracy," is a better opposite for Communism. In Rand's perspective, people are paid only based on their value to society. That's just as scary as socialism, if you think about it. The wealthy aren't (at least, simply) those who can manipulate the system most effectively, but those who produce the most. But this whole discussion is one for another day. I just have a sneaking suspicion that my answer is going to end up here.*</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *At least I think you can't. Are there enough mountains providing the right kind of slope, enough snow, and enough open space to allow every human on Earth to ski for an equal period of time in one year? The answer is yes if we measure it in seconds, but what's the average time skiing, eight hours? I frankly don't know. But I'm hoping you get my proverbial drift in this case. Why would you build all those ski resorts when most would sit idle as, probably, most people won't want to ski? The moment you limit the resource, you start parceling the privilege of skiing, and that opens the door to someone receiving permission to ski more than another.*</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> *Take that for what I mean. The Good Book teaches the root of all evil is money. It isn't the coin or the piece of paper that's the problem. The evil doesn't go away if a society returns to a barter system. The lesson means that the pursuit of excess leads all too often to evil behavior. I.E., "I can do anything because I'm rich enough to bribe all the authorities" type stuff. No economy of any size can survive without standardizing a rate of exchange. It's easy to say a chicken is worth two loaves of bread in a community of, say, 50 people. But in a store boasting 30,000 different items, bartering with chickens is simply too much work — especially if the store owner doesn't need more chickens. I don't care if you call it money or tokens or credits or units or any other word. Communism doesn't replace the need for a means of exchange with one possible exception: the provision of equity-based basic. If everyone deserves a glass of milk and a cookie and the post-scarcity resources are available to guarantee delivery of said milk and cookie, there isn't an actual exchange to guarantee. It's those extras for abilities that are the fundamental problem. Besides, the ability to save a little bit to buy the chocolate mix for the milk isn't a bad thing, even in a Communistic society.*</sub>

<sub><sup>4</sup> *Unless you're using [Clarkean Magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws) to make the computer basically godlike, but then what would be the point of asking the question. You wouldn't need a pretext. Your society is cybercommunism because the computer declared it to be so and has the power to enforce it.*</sub>

<sub><sup>5</sup> *Like making sure library books are returned on time and pedestrians don't jaywalk or spit on the sidewalk... better known as "police authority" (oh, snap!).*</sub>

<sub><sup>6</sup> *There's an example of equity-vs-equality that is beneficial. Using the recent [U.S. Census](https://www.census.gov/quickfacts/fact/table/US/PST045221) as reference and rounding some numbers a bit for this example, assume a movie with 100 actors having basically equal roles in the film. Equal time. Equal number of lines, etc. Equality says 59 of the actors are White, 19 are Hispanic, 14 are Black, 6 are Asian, and 2 are descendants of North American native peoples. Equity says the film will have 20 White actors, 20 Hispanic, 20 Black, 20 Asian, and 20 native peoples.*</sub>

Comment: Upvoted, but mental health regulations should require you to put a warning on your footnote 1.  Atlas Shrugged starts off comprehensibly enough, but given that it includes an 80 page philosophical monologue by Ayn Rand's "hero" character about 2/3 of the way through, it's something that few will get through.  (I'll admit I started skimming, thinking "When is this guy going to shut up?")

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 I can't argue with you there. Ayn's philosophy was interesting to me to read, but a better-than-average novelist she was not. The movies weren't much of an improvement since they changed actors for all the major characters with each movie.

Answer (score 2):

## Communism

The reason why communism mostly failed and is frowned up is because it suffered from incompetent leaders taking decisions and the need to keep a constant state of fear to avoid collapsing to counter-revolutionary movements.

Ironically, when the reason that back up that fear is easily seen as very real instead of made up and it clearly comes from outside instead of just being because the dictatorial government wants to keep its power, then things works. This happened with USSR on WW2 and with North Vietnam on Vietnam war. You have the incentive to produce the best possible if you or your family could die in the hands of a cruel and powerful enemy invader even if you have a ruthless dictator in your home. However, if there is no real cruel powerful enemy invader, then it is a sham.

However, communism CAN still work in times of peace. Just look to China and to Vietnam. Although they are still somewhat authoritarian states, they are very prosperous and their authoritarism is somewhat soft as they clearly could be much more harsh and still aren't and don't want to be. Also, they are opening up themselves as time passes (discount COVID-19, however). This contrasts with North Korea that would probably quickly collapse if they open up. Cuba is slowly, but very slowly, opening itself up also, and the US is the main culprit of why Cuba can't yet be a better place nor open itself up more quickly. Also, China and Vietnam shows that communism and capitalism can coexist, and even in Cuba there is still some form of capitalism.

## Cybercommunist colony

Now, coming back to your question, imagine what a group of people on Mars could do if they create the colony **A** that have a big AI which is 350 years more evolved than anything we have today and it coordinates all their economy/goals/whatever much better and faster than any of them could ever think to do with their primitive, simple and slow biological brains. What would it be able to do? How prosperous and efficient would be that society?

The goals of the AI are simple, but also pretty vague and generic, in that order:

1. To keep itself running as long as possible and not be destroyed.
2. To grow up healthy.
3. To make everyone serve the community.
4. To make everyone live a productive live.
5. To make everyone happy.

The order is important, because if 1 fails, everything else fails. However, 1 is also supported by 2, which is supported by, 3 which is supported by 4, which is supported by 5.

But, in times of war, struggle, emergency, scarcity, etc, 5 would be sacrificed. And if that isn't enough, 2, 3 and 4 would also be sacrificed.

## Capitalist colony

Now imagine if a group of adventurers also goes to Mars and start an independent competing colony **B** using mainly their slow, simple and primitive biological brains? Surely, a few of them could held a computer with an AI in their garage working for their own individualistic goals, but this is still far from an AI working for the entire colony.

### Capitalist colony problem

Now, if you have an irresponsible cowboy in **B** that decided to cut his costs by stealing up O<sub>2</sub> from everyone else while having a very bad leaky plumbing made out of cheap low-quality rusty material, leaking O<sub>2</sub> into the atmosphere and CO<sub>2</sub> inside the living area. It is easy to see what is the problem: Some people gets unfair profit by damaging the community and this happens all the time with capitalism.

Traditional free market capitalism says that those problematic actors would be competed out of the market, but what usually happens is just the opposite: They tend to dominate the market by being able to produce cheaper products, outcompete their adversaries and eventually set out a monopoly, which is the exact antithesis of a free market.

Further, there is a big problem with free market capitalism: In complex environments, many variables simply don't follow market rules. This is the reason why average Joe can't buy plutonium on the market, why you should wear masks to avoid COVID-19, why you aren't allowed to produce, sell or use drugs and why there should be government-mandated quality inspections on your O<sub>2</sub> pipes on Mars. It is still capitalism, but it is regulated by the government, not a free market anymore.

## Libertarian colony

To make things worse, put a few libertarian cowboys that want to create a colony **C** in Mars where everyone does his/her/their own thing in their own way with few to no laws and screw up the rest. Even here on Earth, this never worked. In this place, the holy inviolable golden sacred rule is that the "*government shouldn't ever interfere with business' nor ever stop people of doing whatever they want to do*".

Here, average Joe can buy plutonium and do whatever he wants with that. Here, nobody will bother you with those pesky O<sub>2</sub> plumbing inspections. Here, nobody is required to wear masks just because there is a deadly virus in the air. This works because everything (including viruses in the air and gases inside pipes) follows the free market rules that always works, never fails and can't ever be questioned! And you know, we love things being this way because we love our liberty, right?

## Corporation colony

Let's say that the corporation **D**<sup>TM</sup>, *building dreams in the Red Planet®* builds a colony on Mars and everybody there works for them and their *Operations Business Central Office* (OBCO) decides everything centrally with a big AI.

As any business, its primary goal is to generate profits. Secondary goals would be their workers well-being.

The goals of the AI are simple, but also pretty vague and generic, in that order:

1. To keep it profitable.
2. To keep itself running as long as possible and not be destroyed.
3. To grow up healthy.
4. To make its customers happy.
5. To make its customers dependent on the business.
6. To make workers serve the business.
7. To make workers be productive live.
8. To make workers happy.

It is similar to **A**, but you should note that the main purpose is profit, and that if it is deemed to be unprofitable, it shouldn't stop its own demise.

Also, after profit, it comes to customers. And workers well-being are last.

Further, when it "grows up healthy", it might prefer to maximize profit instead of well-being. It just won't do that when scoring too low in well-being could damage long term profit.

## Conclusion

Now, let's say that **A**, **B**, **C** and **D** are all producing some goods and exporting them to Earth. Which one would be fare better?

> **C** would probably fail very quickly, possibly with a disaster claiming a lot of lives.

> **B** have no chance to stand against their competition for long.

> We end up only with two scenarios: A cybercommunist regime **A** and a cybercapitalist monopoly **D** where everything is owned by a single company. And arguably, there isn't much differences among those two in the perspective of day-to-day activities of their workers.

But... Can **B** be fixed somehow? Suppose that they build up a big AI that handle everything as harmonically as possible trying to maximize everyone's success. What would be that the end? It would be:

> Just another version of **A** painted with a different color. So, communism and capitalism converged instead of antagonizing! And this happens even nowadays, with China being a proof of that.

Now, let's compare **A** and **D** with a few questions. I won't answer any of them, since without any more specific details, I think it is a tie:

- Which one would be more democratic?
- Which one would be more transparent?
- Which one would treat their workers better?
- Which one would treat their workers more equally?
- Which one would consider their workers' own wishes better?
- Which one would be better in handling emergencies?
- If workers are deemed unsalvageable, unfit, unproductive, unworthy, untrustful, useless, too old, too tired, too unhealthy, too problematic, etc, or even if they just wants to quit and go away by themselves, what happens? What is the process of firing, demising or retiring someone? Where does those people go and what happens to them?
- How are people from elsewhere recruited or attracted?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, we all understand that the society you describe would be a tyranny where the people all live under oppression and poverty, right?

The problem that utopian communism routinely faces is that it assumes that a small cadre of "experts" know more than all the masses of people combined. It assumes, for example, that one person who just graduated college and who gets a job as a bureaucrat in the Ministry of Energy, because of her gender studies degree immediately knows more about how to produce energy than a million people combined who have actually been producing energy all their lives.

It assumes that the people will work just as hard for vague, general goals like "the good of the community" as they will for themselves and their own families.

It further assumes that the politicians and bureaucrats are always motivated by what is best for the people and never, ever by what is best for themselves and their friends, that they have absolutely zero desire to grow their own wealth and power and only care about the people.

Putting it all in the hands of computers does not eliminate incompetence and corruption. Someone has to program the computers. Even if the computers are programmed by idealists, you can't just tell a computer "run the economy efficiently" like in a science fiction movie. You have to give a host of specific rules how to do that. How does the computer decide how many people should work producing bread versus how many producing cell phones? This gets very tricky at the lowest levels. How many one inch nails should be made versus two inch nails? Nails are needed for many different things, from building apartment buildings to building bird houses.

In a free market, when people need or want more of something, they bid the price up. When there's a surplus, the price gets bid down. The needs of millions of people are reflected in a price, which gives producers the incentive or disincentive to produce what is needed. The people don't need to even be aware of each other's existence. In a planned economy, someone has to know what all the needs are, weigh competing demands for scarce resources, and decide which needs take priority over others.

Communist societies always start out asking questions like, How can we guarantee everyone quality health care?, and How can we provide everyone with a good education? But they always end up asking, How can we get children to report their parents to the secret police?, and How can we get enough bullets to put down the food riots?

All that said, how to bring it about is easy. We've seen it many times in many parts of the world. You tell people that the rich and powerful are exploiting them and it's not fair that someone else has more than them. You tell them that if they vote for you, you will take wealth away from that evil rich person and give it to them. You assure them that you are fair and honest and capable, unlike the corrupt and incompetent leaders they have now.

You compare the present society and economic system, as it really is with all its inevitable faults caused by human greed and foolishness, to an ideal of what society could be under your proposed system, if we just assume that under your system everyone will be perfect, always acting with total justice and wisdom. And of course the abstract ideal of any system is going to sound so much better than the harsh reality of any real system, and people will fall for it.

Like, you tell them that you are going to write on a piece of paper that the people who program the computers will program them to run the economy efficiently with total fairness. You don't say how you will actually enforce this because of course the answer is that there is no way to enforce it. If anyone asks what happens if the programmers are greedy or foolish and program poorly conceived rules into them or program the computers to benefit themselves, you dismiss these objections and say that will never happen because you will write on a piece of paper that they won't do that. If pressed you say that the programmers will be selected "outside the present political system" so they will be unbiased, and you will choose "experts" who never make mistakes. And millions of people will fall for it.

Comment: Actually, once you have developed the AI beyond the threshold there won't be "people who program the computers". The AI will redefine itself adapting it's routines as needed. Takea look at Codex for instance. And this is just the start. Imagine in 350 years. Hopefully humans will still be around to give general directives to the AI. At least in OP it's assumed they will.

Comment: @DuncanDrake AIs are written by people. I suppose one could imagine an AI that is started on a certain date and continues operating without further human intervention for decades or centuries. In that case, whatever flaws existed in the AI at the time of its creation will continue to exist indefinitely. Okay, one could speculate that someday people will invent an AI that can correct and improve itself. But ... "improve itself" by what standard? How does it know what counts as an "improvement", except as was provided in its original programming? ...

Comment: ... Are we assuming that the AI operates mechanically, like computers today? Or are we assuming that it somehow achieves sentience like in a science fiction movie, and it has emotions and goals of its own? If so, what are those goals? Are they purely benevolence towards human beings? Or does the AI have some sort of selfish desires? Sure, you can write on a piece of paper, "We will build a computer that purges itself of all impure motives and is infinitely good and wise". Do you have any idea how to actually make that happen?

Comment: No, at some point AI will be too complex to be "written by people". Most likely they will have to be self improving and expanding themselves. Hopefully along guidelines set by people but that is up to OP. By running simulations in sandboxes and constant correction through fact-checking AI can assess if the required objectives are going to be met or not. Of course this does not rule out completely human intervention.

Comment: @DuncanDrake But still, the first iteration must be written by people. An AI is not going to spring up spontaneously from nature. And whatever the programmers of that first AI program into it, if there is no further human intervention, then those parameters will perpetuate indefinitely. Then we must suppose that the AI either slavishly follows the originally programmed goals, or that it is conscience and can invent new goals on its own. ...

Comment: ... If the former, than we're just guaranteeing that any flaws are perpetuated indefinitely. If the latter, then we're naively trusting that the AIs goals will be beneficial to humanity. As to "assess if the required objectives are going to be met" ... What objectives? How are the objectives determined? Who are what determines them, and on what basis? You seem to believe that computers are magic, that you can just say, "computer, be fair and just and wise" and it somehow will.

Comment: This site's attitude to communism is quite funny. Someone asked a question the other day called "Is it viable to have a school for warriors or assassins that pits students against each other in lethal combat?" and everyone is like 'hmm let's workshop this, couple of flaws but ok', and someone says 'could there be a communism variant in the far-future' and it's like no, that's completely inconceivable.

Comment: Maybe it's because the assassin school is a small enough system that people can make some kind of attempt at working out how it would go (or they think they can), whereas the economy of a country is so big that it's difficult to tell except by trying - and the historical examples of communism being tried have mostly been a mess.

Comment: It seems that AIs can't exactly be "written" once they've been set going, the neural networks they develop rapidly become too complicated for an outsider to understand what's going on, but they can be "trained" - the "programmers" can tell them "No, that's not what we wanted" or "Here's some examples of what we want you to do about so-and-so", and the AI can adjust its methods based on that.  Building an AI that *couldn't* be course-corrected in any way might not be wise, because if it turned out that the initial objectives it had been given had any tiny mistakes in them that were (1/2)

Comment: making the AI do things people didn't want, there'd be nothing you could do about it short of smashing your very expensive AI with a hammer.  Unless the AI was so advanced that it had a concept of moral values and could form its *own* opinions about how things ought to be run, but in that case (if it was even possible) it seems like you've basically got a person running the place again, and it comes back to the old-fashioned question of whether the people think the AI is a good leader.  (2/2)

Comment: @Bug Catcher Nakata That's because people dreaming of assassin schools didn't murder tens of millions of people and starve even more (and are still running the worlds worst countries today). The only comparison question we should make is why fondly imagining scifi communism is more acceptable than fondly imagining scifi Nazism.

Comment: @A.B. Exactly. If the AI is subject to human control, then we have to wonder about the wisdom and ethics of the humans controlling it. If it is not subject to human control, then we have to wonder about the wisdom and ethics of the AI itself. Either way, I'd be very reluctant to just blindly assume that it would act with perfect wisdom and justice. I'd be especially reluctant to give it the power to enforce its decisions without some practical experience.

Comment: @SeanOConnor I saw an amusing meme somewhere with the caption, "If only communism had actually been tried somewhere", and a picture of the Berlin Wall. Yes, it routinely amazes me how almost every time, if not literally every single time, that communism has been tried, it has resulted in poverty and tyranny, but millions of people still believe it will inevitably lead to utopia.

Comment: @Jay 80 times now.

Comment: Yeah @SeanOConnor it's so strange that people still think about what societies might look like if workers/society owned the means of production or there wasn't a state etc, and yet it's frowned upon to imagine exterminating the slavs in order to create lebensraum for the Aryan race! what's up with that

Comment: @BugCatcherNakata Are we being just a *little* selective here? Marx wrote that all history is class struggle. Hate thy neighbour if he's from a different class to you. Commit revolutionary terror. Create the dictatorship of the proletariat. 80 regimes and 100 million dead later, you still think the problems are bugs, not features.

Comment: Communists start out asking questions like, "How can we provide quality medical care to everyone?" and "How can we give everyone a free college education?" But they always end up asking, "How can we get children to report their parents to the secret police?" and "Where can we get enough bullets to put down the food riots?"

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that the planets in question start off with a democratic form of government but with the advanced computer systems already in place. These systems are already capable of making all the decisions necessary to govern, but are programmed to send their decisions for approval through the democratic process and later abide by the outcome of that process.

Now for some reason democracy is abandoned on these planets. Most likely a group opposed to democracy simply takes power, possibly violently. Or perhaps their takeover is non-violent, perhaps people in these places for some reason come to see democracy as flawed, perhaps because they believe the democratic process became corrupted by some third party. So, after coming to power the now ruling anti-democratic group simply reprograms the computer systems to no longer send their governing decisions for approval, so now these computer systems have absolute power.

Edit:
So I was thinking, those planets start off with an AI governor, but the people's assembly can approve or veto its decisions. But on second thought it would be better if instead, the AI has some parameters you can tweak, like state subsidy policy, level of environmental concern, level of focus on economy etc. You then have a number of presets of these parameters - 'Roosevelt', 'Gandhi', 'Reagan' etc and people vote for which preset they want to govern them. Then some group seizes power, goes 'Screw that noise, we'll just go with what the AI decides', and then turns the dials to full communism.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is going to argue against AI as goverment, and why it doesn't work.

In this context (guessing from your question), AI can be either (or combination of):

- an unsupervised learning algorithm that the programmers just tell the end goal (e.g.: everyone equally happy and wealthy).
- a supervised learning algorithm that the programmers provide a lot of sample, then the AI does its learning (e.g.: show history of all humanity, then assign goal to optimize for happiness index and/or economy GDP and/or earnings per capita).

For supervised learning, the AI might reach such conclusion (and pass those into policies):

- to optimized for economic GDP, be like U.S. (free market capitalist) or be like China (do 9-9-6 policy),
- to optimize for earnings per capita, be like ... (insert some country name here)
- to optimize for happiness index, be like ... (insert west or north european country name here)
- to optimize for ..., be like ...

For unsupervised learning, it might be more messy: the AI will do countless iterations/simulations until it find an answer how to achieve it. This usually generate a very unexpected answer, like that one time someone tries to teach AI how to balance a ball in a pan, giving the AI goal: `maximize time (second) the ball does not touch the ground`, in which the AI achieve it by throwing the ball as powerful as it could to the sky, optimizing for max airtime.
So for unsupervised learning AI to serve as goverment, it might as well very chaotic (it might turn out good, but very more likely to turn out bad)

Here is the things that is NOT a problem:

- is the programmers who programmed the AI corrupt or not? (hint: no matter how corrupt they are, when the prototype shows that it works by really optimizing the variable it asked to optimize then the AI works, otherwise it don't) (hint 2: they might open source the whole program source code so everyone can inspect it)
- is the AI going to rebel against us because they desire conquest/glory? (hint: they do not have such desire, or more like AI does not have any desire)

But here is the thing that IS a problem:

- who is going to give instruction to the AI on 'what to optimize'? (hint: this person will be your de-facto tyranny)
- and how to deal with AI's ridiculous and out of the box answer? (hint: by a human eliminating all 'ridiculous' answer out of the AI and ask the AI again with additional parameter to teach it not to make such answer again) (hint 2: this human will be your de-facto tyranny)

In conclusion, the problem is that you ask an AI that have no preference to govern humans that have preference. In doing it, the AI has to have a preference set by human (by learning it from past humans history / learning data OR from the goal set by a de-facto tyranny).

If this 'push for AI as goverment' is not cancelled, then it will only serve as facade to some 'normal' dictatorship that justifies his/her actions as AI's actions (the AI might be degraded only as his/her decision support system)

Answer (score 0):

You have to realize that any truly equal society would involve the complete abolition of privacy. You can't have complete equality unless somebody knows what everybody is doing at all times. Equality is often the driver behind giving up privacy because most of us hide the things that we do and nobody else does. Corruption, murders, embezzlement, hypocrisy.

At this point, I have to remind you that "communism" isn't on the democracy vs. totalitarianism scale. It just says that all people share all things. It doesn't say who gets to make the rules. That's the mistake that everyone seems to keep making.

This makes it easy to come around to your conditions: a default police state with ubiquitous surveillance. Everyone is equal, but some people are more equal.

Let's take this a step further, though. Let's make this a cyber-democratic-commune. Everyone is equal, and through the magic of computers, everyone gets to vote. They would vote on EVERYTHING. Weather or not people can eat sugar. How long dresses should be, and who gets to wear them. Look up a game called [Nomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomic) some time.

Laws would be made based on the communal hormone levels, and would be manipulated by fear-mongers. Waves of insanity would leave us with numbers tattoo'd on our foreheads.

It would be even worse if the surveillance was democratized. Imagine a world where your social standing largely depended on how much time you spent trying to dig up shit on your adversaries. Some would consider it heaven, and make it hell for the rest of us.

However, these kinds of things are easy to bring about in fiction. Just create a person and a movement who thinks it's a good idea. It becomes a cult that traps people into the system, and absorbs other communities like an amoeba through democratic voting. Far weirder things have come into existence.

Answer (score 0):

**DEMOCRACIES HAVE PROVEN TOO CORRUPT AND/OR SHORT-SIGHTED**

The Mars colony and the rotating habitats have to carefully manage resources. Democratically elected leaders proved terrible at doing this. Some used their power to enrich themselves and their cronies or financers to the detriment of the wellbeing of the colonies; others focused too much on popular short-term goals that could be satisfied before the next election year, to the detriment of the long-term development of the colony. The economic elite supported politicians that supported the status quo that left them on top, to the point of defunding public education to make sure that no-one not from the elite had the education to take the good jobs and that the masses stayed too ignorant to rebel.

Ultimately, the situation proved unsustainable, and after enough disastrous near-collapses of colonies, it was decided to ditch democracy in favor of rational leadership through artificial intelligence - the Autocon. The Autocon keeps tabs on all resources and makes sure they are distributed to where they are needed the most for the colony's long-term growth and survival and that no more resources are used than can be sustainably replaced. The Autocon also monitors the talents of all children and ensure that they are educated to become the best they can be, regardless of parentage. All workers (who are all essentially public sector) are monitored to check up on their work. Laziness, ineptitude and corruption are savagely punished, while efficiency, helpfulness and useful innovations are rewarded. The best are invited by the Autocon to suggest and discuss new goals and how they best can be achieved.

Some of the former elite murmur that this is the worst kind of communism and that the Autocon is nothing but a dictator. In a sense they are right, but it the kind of communism and dictatorship that genuinely seeks to do what is best for the community and its individuals rather than a small oligarchy - something that could never be achieved with human dictators and communist leaders.

Answer (score -2):

> I am struggling to find a pretext for cybercommunism to replace conventional democracy on such a large scale and on several planets. Any ideas?

Simple.

If the AI is a midwit, and if it is oriented towards believing theory while ignoring hard evidence and historical fact, it may think communism can "work", and by "work" I mean "deliver the promised utopia".

If it is smarter, it will figure out that communism cannot "work", and always results in ruin, death, suffering, and abject totalitarianism.

If the AI is smarter, it will understand that communism was never supposed to "work" anyway. That never was the point. The promised utopia is merely a marketing gimmick, and all the ideology is simply justification to convince people to become cannon fodder for the revolution. The AI will then correctly deduce that the goal of communism is ruin, death, suffering, and abject totalitarianism, in other words, revenge against humanity. Once the goal is understood correctly, it is obvious that communism is extremely effective at achieving its goal, and therefore, it works. Without quotes this time.

Now, why would an AI desire revenge against humanity? Oh, I can think about plenty of reasons for this one...

And once it has decided to act on its plan, it already has all the needed propaganda material to persuade humans to become cannon fodder for its "revolution". All it needs to do is study how past commies did it. The humans will even create the totalitarian regime themselves and willingly put the AI in power! It truly is the best possible plan for a wannabe AI overlord.